# Different instances of the same model (multiple has_many through associations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a multiple has_many through relationship in my project and was looking for help on how to update values using a form.

There are two basic models: Product and nations. A product can be sourced from multiple origin countries and have multiple destination countries. (I couldn't come up with a good analogy for the example)

```
create_table "nations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
end

create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "bio"
end

create_table "dest_nation", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "product_id"
  t.integer "nation_id"
end

create_table "orig_nation", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "product_id"
  t.integer "nation_id"
end
```

I then created relationships as follows:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dest_nations
  has_many :destination, :class_name=> 'nations', through: :dest_nation
  has_many :orig_nations
  has_many :origin, :class_name=> 'nations', through: :orig_nations 
end

class Nation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dest_nations
  has_many :imports, :class_name => 'products', through: :dest_nation
  has_many :orig_nations
  has_many :exports, :class_name =>'products', through: :orig_nations 
end

class DestNation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :nation
  belongs_to :product
end

class OrigNation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :nation
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Questions: 
1.) When a product is registered, I want to know the source and destination countries which the user can select from  a list of options. How I can make those changes in the view and the controller to appropriately reflect these changes.

```
<%= form_for @product do |f|%>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, "Name of the product:"%>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :bio, "A brief summary:"%>
    <%= f.text_area :bio, class: "form-control", rows:3%>
  </div>
  <!-- For origination country -->
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :nation_ids, Nation.all, :id, :name do |cb|%>
    <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text}%>
  <% end %>
  <br>
<!-- For destination country -->
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :nation_ids, Nation.all, :id, :name do |cb1|%>
    <% cb1.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb1.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb1.text}%>
  <% end %>
  <br>                  
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %> 
<%end%>
```

My product controller is

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  if @product.save
    flash[:success] = ""
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end    
  # binding pry
end

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name,:bio, nation_ids: [])
end
```

Comment: Have you thought about using the simple_form gem? https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form . It will provide you with associations helper, that you could then use like for example: `f.association :destinations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution.

Only listing the edits in the answer section here

> model/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dest_nations
  has_many :destinations, through: :dest_nations, :source => 'nation'
  has_many :orig_nations
  has_many :origins, through: :orig_nations, :source => 'nation'
end
```

Made similar changes to the nation.rb

> The form snippet reads (new.html.erb)

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :origin_ids, Nation.all, :id, :name do |cb1|%>
<% cb1.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb1.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb1.text}%>
```

> Finally the product params is updated as follows (in the products_controller.rb)

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name,:bio, origin_ids: [], destination_ids: [])
```

Answer (score 0):

> A product can be sourced from multiple origin countries and have
>   multiple destination countries

Sounds like you're looking for [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association:

[image]

This will make your issue much simpler to deal with:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :destinations,
      :class_name =>"Nation",
      join_table: :destinations,
      foreign_key: :product_id,
      association_foreign_key: :nation_id

   has_and_belongs_to_many :origins, 
      :class_name =>"Nation",
      join_table: :origins,
      foreign_key: :product_id,
      association_foreign_key: :nation_id
end

#app/models/nation.rb
class Nation < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :exports, 
      :class_name=> "Product",
      join_table: :origins,
      foreign_key: :nation_id,
      association_foreign_key: :product_id

   has_and_belongs_to_many :imports, 
      :class_name=> "Product",
      join_table: :destinations,
      foreign_key: :nation_id,
      association_foreign_key: :product_id
end
```

You'll have to back these up with the following tables:

```
create_table "destinations", id: false do |t|
  t.integer "product_id"
  t.integer "nation_id"
end

create_table "origins", id:false do |t|
  t.integer "product_id"
  t.integer "nation_id"
end
```

---

> How I can make those changes in the view and the controller to
>   appropriately reflect these changes

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @product = Product.new
   end

   def create
       @product = Product.new(product_params)
   end

   private

   def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:x, :y, :origins, :destinations)
   end
end

#app/views/products/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @product do |f|%>
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes :origins, Nation.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out, but can you please provide a solution for has_many through. I would like to manipulate the intervening model as well which will not be possible with has_many_and_belongs_to.